# CodeIgniter Modular Extensions & the i18n library

Tags: php, codeigniter, internationalization, codeigniter-routing, modularization

I have been using the  CodeIgniter i18n library by Jérôme Jaglale (http://maestric.com/en/doc/php/codeigniter_i18n), which works great for my project.

But since I need to write separate modules, I recently added CodeIgniter Modular Extensions ( https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc ) and the navigation breaks.

How can I solve this issue please, I would love to use both the i18n library & Modular Extensions.

I think my application navigation fails to work because i18n library introduces adds a language segment in the site url, in my case my url is localhost/index.php/en/home and after adding Modular Extensions, my navigation/links stop working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I try to use HMVC with i18n and have similar problem. Below is my solution.

1.first you need to go to here [HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads) select "Branches" to download HMVC extension, don't download the one on github it might not work.

2.Unzip HMVC extension inside the folder copy two files "MY_Loader.php" and "MY_Router.php" from core folder to Codeigniter's "application/core" after that copy "MX" folder from "third_party" to Codeigniter's "application/third_party". By this point your HMVC is installed, however it will not work because i18n cause the problem so if you run your website it might not display.

3.You need to get new version of i18n which support both HMVC and none HMVC, the old version of i18n seems not support HMVC. Go to here [i18n](https://github.com/Crypt/CodeIgniter-i18n) download it and take time to read the description on github.

4.Before this step I suggest you to backup "application/core/MY_Config.php" and "application/core/MY_Lang.php" in case something goes wrong you can reverst back. Unzip i18n inside folder copy file "language.php" from config folder to Codeigniter's "application/config", copy two files "MY_Config.php" and "MY_Lang.php" from core folder to Codeigniter's "application/core", finally copy "MY_language_helper.php" from helpers folder to Codeigniter's "application/helpers". So far you have new i18n installed, but you need to configure it to make it work, otherwise you might get error message.

5.Open "application/core/MY_Config.php" and replace the line `require_once APPPATH . "libraries/MX/Config.php";` to `require_once APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Config.php";` then open "application/core/MY_Lang.php" replace the line `require APPPATH . "libraries/MX/Lang.php";` to `require APPPATH . "third_party/MX/Lang.php";`. Why? because it point to the wrong directory, the MX folder is located in "third_party" not "libraries" in case you don't know, if you don't change it you might get error message.

6.To add new language(Not create language file) you need to open "application/config/language.php". You see at top the code block with comment says "Supported Languages" there already have English and Russian language configure for you just need to copy the template and change to the language you want, it's very easy. Be aware folder's name must exactly the same as folder in "application/language".

7.According to i18n github description you need to add these line

`$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(.+)$'] = "$2";`

`$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)$'] = $route['default_controller'];`

to the "application/config/routes.php". Be aware this line `$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(.+)$'] = "$2";` in old i18n probably is `$route['^(en|de|fr|nl)/(.+)$'] = "$1";` the difference is "$1" have to change to "$2", otherwise you will got problem.

8.To create language file is same as the method you did in old i18n. Now test your website with multi-language to make sure everything work fine.

9.Create your module. How? Create a folder name "modules" inside Codeigniter's application folder, inside modules folder you can start to create your module. That's say you want to create a module call foo, you just need to create a folder name it "foo" and then inside foo folder you can create three folders controllers, models and views. Create a php file with name foo with the code below

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Foo extends MX_Controller 
 {

     public function index()
     {
         echo "<h1>class foo this is module test</h1>";
     }
 }
```

Enter url to run your module, if you see "class foo this is module test" then it work.
Remember module class must extends from MX_Controller.

If you still encounter any problem just ask.